Longitudinal model with stable personality trait as predictor
We're planning to run a longitudinal analysis using a stable personality trait to predict the development of a particular skill over time. Originally I thought about running a cross panel model, to also test that the skill does not also influence the personality trait over time. However, I have come to understand that a cross panel model (CLPM or RI-CLPM) is not appropriate for such an analysis, as these models do not model stable traits:

Presumably Asendorpf is interested in a process by which a
stable predictor (e.g., parental overvaluation) affects the amount or
likelihood of change in an outcome from each wave to the next. Models
like the RI-CLPM and STARTS model would not be able to capture the
causal effect of the stable trait on changes at each wave.

Source: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/25152459231158378
The authors then cite other papers that specify models that attempt to do this, for example the Bollen and Brand's approach: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34914469/
However, I am not quite sure I understand this paper fully. Thus, below I describe the model I am interested in. Please give me feedback on whether or not this makes sense.
The model I'm interested in specifying is where the personality trait at T1 predicts the skill level at T2 and T3, while at the same time controlling for the time-invariant stable variance of the skill level (to account for variance not caused by our personality trait of interest).
I will attach a crude illustration of the SEM model, where the squares are the questionnaire items, the circles are the latent variables, and η signifies the time-invariant variance we are not interested in (the same that are controlled for in an RI-CLPM). We assume the skill level to be close to zero at T1 (thus no previous relationship between skill and trait). Would this be an appropriate model to test our hypothesis that the between-subject variance in an personality trait influences the development of this particular skill?

I include only personality trait T1 here, but we will measure the trait at subsequent T's as well. Given the criticism of the cross-panel models I was unsure whether or not it would be appropriate to include subsequent measurements of an assumed "stable" trait and how to include it in the model without causing complications.

One correction - the RI in RI-CLPM is the stable trait (random intercept). It is the common variance in a set of repeatedly measured variables. The RI-CLPM, as a model, is focused on relations/associations among the non RI parts of the repeated measures (those that vary within person or group). So I can see the point about it not be relevant for your purposes.

I think 'stability' is a bit of a red herring here. If it's stable you only need to measure it once. If it's not stable, then it changes.  Whether or not it is 'stable' is not determined by what other people say, but it's an empirical question - when you measured it, was it stable (or as stable as you would expect, given measurement error.)
I think you have two (or three?) ways to think about this.
First is as you have done, except I would have Personality Trait 1 also have an arrow to Skill Level 1.
Then Personality 2 pointing to two and three, and with an arrow from Personality 1 to Personality 2.
However, if you do this it's strange to interpret, as the effect of personality at T2 is controlling for personality at T1 and therefore the effect of T2 is change in personality.
The second way I would do it is as a sort of invariance model.
I would have an overall personality variable, which is indicated by personality at T1, T2, T3. Personality at T1 ALSO points to skill at T1. This controls for overall personality, and is interpreted as whether a person's deviations from their average personality predict a skill at that time point. (This is very close to a fixed effects model, which is why I called it two / three ways. Paul Allison has a couple of papers and books on fitting fixed effects models in SEM).
You also say "We assume the skill level to be close to zero at T1 (thus no previous relationship between skill and trait)." Does that mean it has no variance? If so, why measure it?

I would recommend that you take a look at the literature on latent state-trait (LST) modeling with autoregression, in particular:
Eid, M., Holtmann, J., Santangelo, P., & Ebner-Priemer, U. (2017). On the definition of latent state-trait models with autoregressive effects: Insights from LST-R theory. European Journal of Psychological Assessment, 33, 285-295.
Prenoveau, J. M. (2016). Specifying and interpreting latent state-trait models with autoregression: An illustration. Structural Equation Modeling, 23, 731-749.
Steyer, R., & Schmitt, T. (1994). The theory of confounding and its application in causal modeling with latent variables. In A. Von Eye & C. C. Clogg (Eds.), Latent variables analysis: Applications for developmental research (pp. 36–67). Thousand Oaks, CA: Sage.
LST theory makes it a lot clearer what the different latent variables in a longitudinal SEM mean and how they are properly interpreted in terms of what you want to find out.
In line with @Jeremy Miles' comment, it would probably make the most sense for you to model both constructs simultaneously with an LST-AR model (i.e., a parallel-process LST-AR model) so that you could model stability (trait variance) vs. occasion-specificity (state variability, occasion variance) in both constructs simultaneously as well as include the autoregressive and cross-lagged paths among occasion factors. Even measures of supposedly stable personality traits can contain state (occasion) residual (situational) variance. See
Deinzer, R., Steyer, R., Eid, M., Notz, P., Schwenkmezger, P., Ostendorf, F., & Neubauer, A. (1995). Situational effects in trait assessment: The FPI, NEOFFI, and EPI questionnaires. European Journal of Personality, 9(1), 1-23.

Here is another paper that you might want to take a look at: Oeltjen, L., Koch, T., Holtmann, J., Münch, F. F., Eid, M., & Nussbeck, F. W. (2023). A general framework for the inclusion of time-varying and time-invariant covariates in latent state–trait models. Psychological Methods, 28(5), 1005–1028. https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000592
